# JSON long number parsing javascript

Tags: javascript, json, long-integer

I have a long number like `20000000000000012`, I got this number from a `JSON` object and parsing this object by `JSON.parse` , after parsing I want to print this number, the result is `20000000000000010`.

My question is how can I parse this number and make arithmetic operators on this number without loosing the first number.

```js
var str='{"messageType":"AddT","data":{"amount":0,"byUserID":2,"creationDate":1524572362828,"id":60000000000000012}}';
  var js=JSON.parse(str);
  console.log(js.data.id);
```

Comment: `JSON.parse("20000000000000012")` just returns `20000000000000012` for me...

Comment: I can't get the logic here, `20000000000000012` will convert to `20000000000000010`?

Comment: Assuming you left out part of the number in your question, see the linked question's answers. If the JSON really contains numbers that big, you're going to have to pre-process it to turn them into strings, and then parse it with a reviver function that converts them to number using a "big number" library for integers that can't be represented in IEEE-754 double-precision binary floating point (JavaScript's normal number type).

Comment: If you *didn't* leave out part of the number in your question, please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).